# How to remove space between numbers and avoid if there is non-numeric value before number?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
   String textString = "Power for CH2 234 45";
```

I need a regex to remove white spaces between numbers but also want to avoid if there is a non-numeric value before a number like

```
textString ="Power for CH2 23445"
```

Comment: Nitin Thakor, does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @IntoVoid Your answer is perfect for my question. In another scenario, I want to change the whole string like this   "Power for CH2 234 45"   to this "23445".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
String result = textString.replaceAll("\\b(\\d+)\\s+(?=\\d)", "$1");
```

The result would be:

> Power for CH2 23445

So exactly what you wanted

Comment: I just want the numeric value from the string like this 23445   Sorry for the lack of information in question.

Comment: Than you should check out @Eyosiyas answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66983095/13187363

Answer (score 2):

Remove all except the digits.
Sample code looks like this.

```
String extracted = textString.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Comment: Yours also removes the "Power for CH" infront of the numbers. If I understood OP correctly, than it should keep all the text

Comment: I guess OP wants something like I did in my Answer. But I could be wrong here, since the instructions aren't that clear to me

Comment: So true, the question isn't clear enough.

Comment: it will also add the number 2 after H to the String like 223445 results should be 23445.

Comment: @NitinThakor OP just added a comment under my answer, explaining that he actually wanted the numbers only. Like your regex pattern does it

Answer (score 2):

**Here is my solution to the problem :**

***input*** :

> "234 234 Power 234 234 for CH2 234 45"

***output*** :

> 234234 Power 234234 for  CH2 23445

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       String textString = "234 234 Power 234 234 for CH2 234 45";

       String[] arrayString = textString.split(" ");
       String result = "";
       for(int i = 0 ; i<arrayString.length;i++) {
           String str = arrayString[i];
           try {
               Integer.parseInt(str); 
               result = result + str;
           }catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
               result =  result.trim() + " " + str + " ";
           }
       }
       System.out.println(result.trim());
}
```

Comment: Didn't OP want a regex pattern. Also I would use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Let's help you figure this out yourself:

0. It helps to use a service like [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) to quickly create some test cases and test them.
1. Let's start with detecting whitespaces between two numbers. The regex for whiteSpace is `\s`, for digits it is `\d`. So `<digit><whitespace><digit>` would be `\d\s\d`
2. In case you want to remove more than one whitespace between digits, you can use `*` (zero or more) or `+` (one or more). Now we need to figure out which one to use. If we use the `*`, we have a hit between two digits regardless of if they have a whitespace in between. You can already feel like it is of more use to only have a hit if it has at least one whitespace, thus we use `+`, like so: `\d\s+\d`
3. Now we need to know if there exists some non-digit character in the same "word". A word is split by any character that is not a letter or a number. A letter is `\w`, a number was `\d`, a letter or a number character is thus `[\w\d]`, to negate this (NOT a letter or a number) we can use `[^ ... ]`: `[^\w\d]` We also need at least one, but possibly more digits: `+`
   The new regex is thus: `[^\w\d]\d+\s+\d`
4. A new number can also be at the beginning of the string; `^`. To make an "or" we can use `|`. We also need some brackets to correctly space the "or", let's use a non-capturing group for that: `(?: ... )`. We then get `(?: ^ | [^\w\d] ) \d+\s+\d` (spaces added for clearity, remove them before you use the regex)
5. Finally, we specifically want to remove the detected whitespaces, use a capturing group for that: `( ... )`: `(?: ^ | [^\w\d] ) \d+ (\s+) \d`, now simply replace the captured group with an empty string, which is left as an exercise to the reader.